# Advice on which is the best way to make my website different for different users. (guests/members)

Tags: php, html, css

**Sceanario** : I have just finished the design for my website and am currently converting it to be ready to go live with PHP. Currently, my index page has a "profile_card"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sfmxl.png

This obviously is what i want my logged in members to see, Its a basic sum up of their account on my site.

But when a guest views the same page i would like them to instead see this,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXJo6.png

**Question**: How can i make it so that when a logged in member views my website they see their "profile card" and guests who are not logged in view the "sign up button".

**Attempted Solution**,
make a function that includes a file called player_card.php which has all the HTML, PHP and MySQL inorder to get the user's details if the session ['id'] is set, else show the button.
//I have ran into problems attempting this as some of the variables that are called in the profile_card.php file do not reteive their values from the index.php as i have it routed like this 
index.php -> global_func.php -> function_ProfileCard -> include profile_card.php.

What would you advise is the easiest way to do this? I hope i have made everything clear and understandable but if i havn't or you have any questions that would further help come to a solution, please ask.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: You should just set and check a [session variable](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) for logged in users.

Comment: Thats what i tried, but my profile card is about 30 lines of HTML, I would have to echo each line out and change it so the HTML works inside of the PHP.

Comment: *tongue in cheek* but... ...I advise against the "Hey you" phrasing... :D

Comment: Haha it was on for development purpose but ill make sure ill change it prior release ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your comments:

> You should just set and check a session variable for logged in users. – PeeHaa

> Thats what i tried, but my profile card is about 30 lines of HTML, I would have to echo each line out and change it so the HTML works inside of the PHP. – user1171731

You can simply use HTML in your PHP code. For example like:

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) { ?>

// your html for logged in users here

<?php } else { ?>

// your html for guests here

<?php }
```

Or perhaps better readable:

```
<?php

if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    require('loggedin.php');
} else {
    require('guest.php');
}
```

And in for example `loggedin.php` you can do something like (note this is just a simple example):

```
echo '<h1>Logged in</h1>';
echo '<p>blablablab</p>';
```

Or using the HEREDOC syntax:

```
$str = <<<EOD
<h1>Logged in</h1>
<p>blablablabla</p>
EOD;
```

Comment: Ah, see i was unsure about your first one, i thought it was more a cheat way to do it so i wasn't sure. But thanks for clearing that up!